# Matrix trace derivatives

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Hi I am trying to take derivatives of the matrix trace.
I do know that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} Tr[A x]= A^\top
$$
Now assuming $x$ is a complex square matrix,
I am trying to calculate

$$
\frac{d}{dx}Tr[x x^\top], \quad \frac{d}{dx} Tr[x x^\dagger]
$$ 
Where $x^\top$ Is the matrix transpose and $x^\dagger$ is the hermitian transpose (complex transpose).

How can I go about calculating these derivatives? Are the results the same? Does the transpose or complex transpose change anything? I am very bad with derivatives of matrix traces any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you can proceed as follows:$f(x+h)=Tr\left[\left(x+h\right)^{T}\left(x+h\right)\right]=Tr\left[x^{T}x+h^{T}x+x^{T}h+h^{T}h\right]$

$=f(x)+\underbrace{2Tr\left[x^{T}h\right]}_{first-order\,term}+Tr\left[h^{T}h\right]$

Now by choosing $h=tE_{i,j}$ we obtain that the $i,j^{th}$ partial derivative is:

$2Tr\left[x^{T}tE_{i,j}\right]=2tTr\left[x^{T}E_{i,j}\right]=t\left(\underbrace{2x_{i,j}}_{i,j^{th}\,partial}\right)$

and so $\frac{d}{dx}Tr\left[x^{T}x\right]=2x$

Comment: How do you choose $h=tE_{i,j}$? What is t and E? How did you get the result from the first order term? It seemed you only used that term to find the answer. And how did you actually compute the trace needed? I do not get how you got the last equality

Comment: $h$ was simply an arbitrary matrix perturbation to help me identify the first order term in the expansion of $f(x)=Tr\left[x^{T}x\right]$. The first order terms represents the linear transformation that represents the derivative. To obtain partial derivatives we make the choice $h=tE_{i,j}$ where $t$ is a scalar (generally presumed to be small) and $E_{i,j}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $i,j^{th}$ position and $0$ elsewhere and we insert this choice of $h$ into the first order term (partial derivatives are just the derivative transformation fed with a standard unit vector).

Comment: To compute the trace notice that most entries of $x^{T}E_{i,j}$ are $0$. In fact, I think $x^{T}E_{i,j}$ is only non-zero in the $j^{th}$ column. The trace will only look for the $j,j^{th}$ entry of $x^{T}E_{i,j}$ (since I think all other diagonal entries are $0$). This can be deduced from the formula for multiplication of two matrices. Sorry my comment was so unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and help. So is $Tr[x^\top E_{i,j}]=x_{ij}?$ where did the 2 come from? I see the 2  outside the trace, did you bring that into the result or is there a factor of 2 coming from the trace result? Sorry this is very unclear to me, thanks again! And do you mean , E is just the identity matrix?

Comment: No problem. Actually the $2$ came from the expansion of $f(x+h)$. Notice that in that expansion we have two terms that have linear dependence on $h$, namely $Tr\left[x^{T}h\right]$ and $Tr\left[h^{T}x\right]$. Since taking the trace of a matrix respects transposition then these should be equal. So we get $2Tr\left[x^{T}h\right]$. I believe $Tr\left[x^{T}E_{i,j}\right]=x_{i,j}$. Also note that $Tr\left[xx^{T}\right]=Tr\left[x^{T}x\right]$.

Comment: Now I understand everything.  Thanks a lot for all of your explanations here and also below!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: @user71352 Just a question for you, I can ask it as a new question if its too much to answer here. ( I understand if so).  Using these results that I now understand
$$
\frac{\partial (X X^\top)}{\partial X}= 2X,\quad \frac{\partial (X X^\top)}{\partial X^\top}= 2X^\top;
$$
I was wondering, what is this result
$$
\frac{\partial (X X^\top)}{\partial X^\dagger}=?
$$
Is it zero?  I think it should be zero since I am differentiating wrt $X^\dagger$ , but in the trace is only $X, X^\top$.  Or is it $ 2 X^\dagger?$  Thanks a lot! ( Sorry for my lack of intution on these basic derivatives)

Comment: In the sense of Wirtinger derivatives I believe $\frac{\partial\left(XX^{T}\right)}{\partial X^{\dagger}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial\left(XX^{T}\right)}{\partial\mathcal{R}X^{T}}+i\frac{\partial\left(XX^{T}\right)}{\partial \mathcal{I}X^{T}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(2\mathcal{R}X^{T}+2i\mathcal{I}X^{T}\right)+i\left(-2\mathcal{I}X^{T}+2i\mathcal{R}X^{T}\right)\right)=\mathbf{0}$ where $\mathcal{R}X$ and $\mathcal{I}X$ denote real and imaginary parts of the matrix $X$.

Comment: @user71352 Very clear, thanks a lot! If you have any specific references for any of this material let me know.  I am interested in learning more of this stuff opposed to keep posting questions.  Thanks again.

Comment: I personally learned about wirtinger derivatives through Hormander's book on several complex variables. If you are interested in a Taylor expansion approach to wirtinger derivatives you might enjoy this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.5170.pdf

Comment: @user71352 Thanks a lot, sorry for the delayed reply!  I've been trying to go through all of this stuff as much as possible.  (Still not so intuitive for me whereas  derivatives of tensors of rank <2 I can happily do).

Comment: Thanks @user71352. This was instructive to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the double-dot (:) product to write the two functions
$$\eqalign{
  f &= \operatorname{tr}(XX^T) = X:X \cr
  h &= \operatorname{tr}(XX^H) = X^*:X \cr\cr
}$$
Then the corresponding differentials and gradients are easily calculated as 
$$\eqalign{
  df &= 2X:dX \cr
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= 2X \cr\cr
  dh &= X^*:dX + X:dX^* \cr
  \frac{\partial h}{\partial X} &= X^* \cr
  \frac{\partial h}{\partial X^*} &= X \cr\cr
}$$
The Wirtinger notion of treating $X^*$ and $X$ as independent variables was used.

Comment: Thanks I follow your answer.  How come the result is not also 2x for the hermitian case,h? Is it intuitive or obvious why there's no factor of 2? I see why the result is 2x for the first example for f ,  but not for $\partial_x h(x)$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Integrals For the Hermitian case note that if we expand $f(x)=Tr\left[xx^{H}\right]$ after perturbing $x$ by $h$ we get $f(x+h)=Tr\left[(x+h)(x+h)^{H}\right]=Tr\left[xx^{H}\right]+Tr\left[xh^{H}\right]+Tr\left[hx^{H}\right]+Tr\left[hh^{H}\right]$. So the first order term is $Tr\left[xh^{H}\right]+Tr\left[hx^{H}\right]$ which is not symmetric in $x$ and $h$ (due to the conjugation). This is why there is no $2$ in the derivative.